# Add some html in a menu

Tags: 7, theming

I try to add some html in "secondary nav".

A little bit like that :

```
    <ul>
      <li>
        <div>
          MY CUSTOM HTML
        </div>
      </li>
      <li><a>First link</a></li>
      <li><a>Second link</a></li>
    </ul>
```

(my menu is not a block).

Do you know how can it be done? By template suggestion or a function for example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For menus that are printed by invoking `theme('links__YOUR_MENU')`, you can use the following code and place it in your theme's `template.php` file:

```
function YOUR_THEME_links__system_main_menu(&$variables) {
  // Copy here the code from theme_links() function and adjust it to your liking.
}
```

See the source for `theme_links()` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/theme_links/7).

For menus in blocks, you can do that using `theme_menu_tree__YOUR_MENU()` override in your theme's `template.php` file. Here's example code that will work for the main menu:

```
function YOUR_THEME_menu_tree__main_menu(&$variables) {
  $your_custom_html  = '<li><div>your custom HTML</div></li>';
  return '<ul class="menu clearfix">' . $your_custom_html . $variables['tree'] . '</ul>';
}
```

This will add the content before menu links.

Comment: You're welcome - glad it helped.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Menu HTML](https://www.drupal.org/project/menu_html) module. It's the best way to allow the admin to add html to the menu item title.